# Visual Studio 2012: Reporting Tab missing from Toolbox

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting, .net-2.0, toolbox

I am using visual studio 2012 and I am unable to find the Reporting Tab in the Toolbox control. Why is that? Is there anything wrong with the installations? Or is it because I am working on .Net Framework 2.0? Please help

Comment: Surely you don't have an old enough version of ReportViewer, you'd have to dig up version 8.0.0.0 somewhere.  Still targeting 2.0 makes exceedingly little sense, target 3.5

Comment: What If I say I can't move this project to 3.5 or higher? Isn't there any solution other than this?